# Fil rows in df.column betwen rows if number of rows between is less than something

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a df where i want to fill the rows in column values with True if the number of rows between values True in column values is less then two.

| counter | values |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | True |
| 2 | False |
| 3 | False |
| 4 | True |
| 5 | False |
| 6 | True |
| 7 | True |
| 8 | False |
| 9 | True |
| 10 | False |
| 11 | False |

The result i want is like the df below:

| counter | values |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | True |
| 2 | False |
| 3 | False |
| 4 | True |
| 5 | True |
| 6 | True |
| 7 | True |
| 8 | True |
| 9 | True |
| 10 | False |
| 11 | False |

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can make groups starting with True, if the group is 2 items (or less), replace with True. Then compute the boolean OR with the original column:

```
N = 2
fill = df['values'].groupby(df['values'].cumsum()).transform(lambda g: len(g)<=N)
df['values'] = df['values']|fill  ## or df['values'] |= fill
```

output (here as new column value2 for clarity):

```
    counter  values  values2
0         1    True     True
1         2   False    False
2         3   False    False
3         4    True     True
4         5   False     True
5         6    True     True
6         7    True     True
7         8   False     True
8         9    True     True
9        10   False    False
10       11   False    False
```

Other option that works only in the particular case of `N=2`, check if both the row before and after is True:

```
df['values'] = df['values']|(df['values'].shift()&df['values'].shift(-1))
```